# Neo4jClient and Cypher Query have difference order returned results

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I'm very new to Neo4j, Neo4jClient and Cypher Query.
I'm implementing Graphity Data Models and Algorithms. So, i have my own egonetwork on my Neo4j Graph Database.
Here is my Cypher Query i'm trying to retrieve egonetwork of a specified user.

```
MATCH(user:User {userID : '1'})-[:ego1*]->(friend)-[:LATEST_ACTIVITY]->(latest_activity)-[:NEXT*]->(next_activity)
RETURN friend, latest_activity, next_activity
```

Here is the result: [image]
So, you see, the order is : **2 3 4 (userID)**

And here is my converted code with Neo4jClient

```
var query = graphClient.Cypher.Match("(user:User {userID : '1'})-[:ego1*]->(friend)-[:LATEST_ACTIVITY]->(latest_activity)-[:NEXT*]->(next_activity)").
                Return((friend, latest_activity, next_activity) => new
                {
                    friends = friend.As<User>(),
                    latest_activity = latest_activity.As<Activity>(),
                    next_activities = next_activity.CollectAs<Activity>()
                }).Results;
        List<User> friendList = new List<User>();
        List<List<Activity>> activities = new List<List<Activity>>();
        List<Activity> activity, tmp;
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            friendList.Add(item.friends);
            Console.Write("UserID: " + item.friends.userID + ". Activities: ");
            activity = new List<Activity>();
            activity.Add(item.latest_activity);
            Console.Write(item.latest_activity.timestamp);
            foreach (var i in item.next_activities)
            {
                activity.Add(i.Data);
                Console.Write(i.Data.timestamp);
            }
            activities.Add(activity);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

This is the result of the code above:
[image]

The order is **3 2 4 (userID)** you see.

Could you please explain me why and tell me how to fix ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your queries are certainly different; the one using Neo4jclient for example, has a `collect` in it. They'll follow different execution plans and unless you specify it explicitly, they can return their results in a different order.

Use `ORDER BY` to specify the order. You can't make any assumptions otherwise.

I've even seen queries return results in a different order when there was only a difference in letter case (lower vs upper case letters).

Comment: Yep. If you don't specify an ORDER BY, the database has the rights to return the data in whatever way is the quickest to do so, and that may be inconsistent between calls, even without the query text changing.

Comment: @TathamOddie So, how can i retrieve the ego network? Because i think the power of Graphity Data Model is never use any sorting algorithm, such as ORDER BY? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you care about order of results, you need to use ORDER BY. If you don't care, then don't use it. It's really that simple.